# SQL Server deny schema and grant permisson to some tables from denyed schema

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, schema

I have a database in SQL Server where users have no permissions to access to some schemas, but I need them to be able to select data from some tables from denied accesse schemas.

Comment: Don't use deny. Users have no permissions by default so all you need to do is grant SELECT on the specific tables.

Comment: Imagine the schema has 30 tabelas, how can I limit access to tables from schema, as default even tha new tables are created, and alow to access to some tables.

Comment: Non-privileged users have no access to tables by default., existing or new. All you need to do us grant SELECT permissions on "some" tables.

Comment: When I create a user and give access to the table in the user mapping, the user has access to all tables, because of the role public... I'm not being hable to create a user without access

Comment: Public does not have permissions by default. If you don't want all users to have such permissions, revoke those from public.

Comment: They have no permissions, but they can "see definition" from the schema. If I want them not to see the schema , I have to block deny the see definition, them I can grant to acess table from the schema.

Comment: So you mean you want to prevent users from viewing the definition of an object they have permissions to access? You could do that with `DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::YourSchema TO YourUser;`